# call overwritten parent function from a child in php

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, parent-child

How is it possible to call a overwritten parent function recursively from a child instance? Since I'm not using static methods I can't use `parent::method()` but have to do somehow different. I have a feeling that there is a better approach to my problem, maybe through a design pattern. This is my class structure:

```
class Creature {
    public function eat() {
        // feed and digest
    }
}

class Mammal extends Creature {
    public function eat() {
        // gather and chew
    }
}

class Human extends Mammal {
    public function eat() {
        // have a meal
    }
}

class WesternPerson extends Human {
    public function eat() {
        // use knife & fork
    }
}

$me = new WesternPerson();
$me->eat();
```

Calling `eat()` shall go recursively upwards from the special to the very abstract class. Most simple way would be if I could call the parent function with the same name from within the overwritten one. But I know, it's overwritten, so I can't.

Comment: `parent::method()` isn't a static call (although it kinda looks like it). Just use that one & you're fine.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16925581/2153758

Comment: Thanks alot! I obviously was confused because of the `::` operator. I's clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::` isn't just for static methods.  It is the scope resolution operator. It is used any time you want to utilized a function that exists in scope other then your contextual scope.

`parent`, `static`, and `self` are language constructs that reference different scopes that relate to your calling scope.

So in this case

```
 parent::eat()
```

will call the Human::eat in the WesternPerson::eat context (ie $this will mean the WesternPerson Instance in the Human::eat context)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments,  calling `parent::eat()` would work just fine