# PHP parent scope resolution operator

Tags: php, class, scope, operator-keyword

I was wondering how I should interpret the following code (source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    protected function myFunc() {
        echo "MyClass::myFunc()\n";
    }
}

class OtherClass extends MyClass
{
    // Override parent's definition
    public function myFunc()
    {
        // But still call the parent function
        parent::myFunc();
        echo "OtherClass::myFunc()\n";
    }
}

$class = new OtherClass();
$class->myFunc();
?>
```

My question is: why is the scope resolution operator ('::') used to access the parent function:

parent::myFunc();

To me, the double colon suggests a static member / method. When creating the OtherClass object:

$class = new OtherClass();

there will be a new instance (object) of the OtherClass. But will there be an instance of the parent class at the same time? How should I interpretet this?

I understand the idea of creating a new object from the extended OtherClass, but how should I interpret its parent class: like a static class or like an object (copy of class)?

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875728/476

Comment: *...the double colon, is a token that allows access to static, constant, **and overridden properties or methods of a class**.*

Comment: It is called the *scope resolution operator*, not the "static access operator"… It *resolves* something, it has little to do with static access.

Answer (score 1):

An object of class `OtherClass` is also an object of class `MyClass` because class `OtherClass` extends class `MyClass`. It has all the properties and methods of `MyClass` but some of the methods might be redefined in `OtherClass`.

The scope resolution operator is used both to access static class members and methods (using class name, [`self`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) or [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)) but also to access methods defined in the parent class (using [`parent`](http://php.net/manual/it/keyword.parent.php)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

`parent::myFunc();` is not a static invocation, it is a bit confusing that it used the same operator though. You only need this operator if you have overridden the method and want to call the parent method.

> there will be a new instance (object) of the OtherClass. But will there be an instance of the parent class at the same time? How should I interpretet this?

Because `OtherClass` extends `MyClass` the single object you constructed is an instance of both these classes at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it makes sense